# Razor pay give payment amount as one rupee incorrectly

Tags: javascript, razorpay

I am trying to add razorpay payment gateway to my website. I use [this](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/quick-integration/) method. I used code like below,

```js
 

document.querySelector('.razor').setAttribute('data-amount', 4200)
```

```html
    <form action="https://www.example.com/payment/success/" method="POST">
<script class="razor"
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="rzp_live_1vs8SzfbPyOPH1" 
    data-currency="INR"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Acme Corp"
    data-image="https://i.imgur.com/sscxwyv.png"
    data-prefill.name=""
    data-prefill.email=""
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

This code give payment amount as one rupee instead of 42 rupees. Where is the error happened? Code pen link [here](https://codepen.io/codepenju/pen/ExwBvdX)

Comment: Your external 'razor' script runs before you set the amount. Perhaps refrain from setting the script `src` until you have finished modifying the necessary data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using data-amount you should use amount only

`(document.querySelector('.razor').setAttribute('amount', 4200)`

this might help you to resolve your problem [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kaN2.png)